# How to input value in mysql depend on date?

Tags: javascript, php

Can someone help me? What i'm trying to do is, for example the date today is '2018-05-08' then if user enter on input text it will go on column name "ONE" and the date to column name "DAY1" then if the date is still '2018-05-08' and user enter again the value on ONE will be updated. But if the date is '2018-05-09' it will go on column name "TWO" and date to "DAY2" and if date is still 2018-05-09' it will just update "TWO". If the date is '2018-05-10' it will go on column name "THREE" and date to "DAY3". The DAY1 to DAY2 is good, but even the date is for DAY3 it's just updating the "DAY2" and not inserting into "DAY3". Please help me. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ASD</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
   include 'db.php';
   $month = date('M');
   $day1 = date('D');
   $day = date('d');
   $tot = 0;
   $datetocheck = '2018-05-08';
   if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
       $sal = $_POST['sal'];
       $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM dates WHERE month='$month' and username='mrpopo'";
       $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);   
       $resultChecka = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
       if ($resultChecka >0){
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
              $one = $row['one'];
              $two = $row['two'];
              $three = $row['three'];
              $four = $row['four'];
              $day1 = $row['day1'];
              $day2 = $row['day2'];
              $day3 = $row['day3'];
              $day4 = $row['day4'];
              if ($day1 == $datetocheck) {
                 $sql23 = "UPDATE `dates` SET one='$sal' WHERE username='mrpopo' ";
                 mysqli_query($conn, $sql23);
              }
              elseif($day1 !=$datetocheck){
                 $sql23 = "UPDATE `dates` SET two='$sal', day2='$datetocheck' WHERE username='mrpopo' ";
                 mysqli_query($conn, $sql23);
              }
              elseif($day2==$datetocheck){
                 $sql23 = "UPDATE `dates` SET two='$sal' WHERE username='mrpopo' ";
                 mysqli_query($conn, $sql23);
              }
              elseif($day2 !=$datetocheck){
                 $sql23 = "UPDATE `dates` SET three='$sal', day3='$datetocheck' WHERE username='mrpopo' ";
                 mysqli_query($conn, $sql23);
              }
              elseif($day3 == $datetocheck){
                 $sql23 = "UPDATE `dates` SET three='$sal' WHERE username='mrpopo' ";
                 mysqli_query($conn, $sql23);
              }
              elseif($day3!=$datetocheck){
                 $sql23 = "UPDATE `dates` SET four='$sal', day4='$datetocheck' WHERE username='mrpopo' ";
                 mysqli_query($conn, $sql23);
              }
              elseif ($day4==$datetocheck) {
                 $sql23 = "UPDATE `dates` SET four='$sal' WHERE username='mrpopo' ";
                 mysqli_query($conn, $sql23);
              }

         }
      }
      else{
        $sql= "INSERT INTO `dates` (one, username,month,day1) VALUES ('$sal', 'mrpopo', '$month', '$datetocheck') ";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      }  
   }
?>
<form method="post">
<label><?php echo $day1.' '. $month .' '.$day; ?></label><input type="text" name="sal" >
<button name="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you are ever going to get past elseif($day1 !=$datetocheck) . The date is going to match or not for day1. Your going to have to figure out what day you need to work with then decide what to update. Maybe days diff from datecheck and sal.

Comment: i realized that now sir Jason K. ty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what do you want but if i underestood correctly you can use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ASD</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="user";
    $password="password";
    $dbname="dbname";
    $dsn="mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname";
try{
    $connect=new PDO ($dsn,$username,$password);
    $connect->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
    }catch(PDOException $error){
          echo "Error in connect".$error->getMessage();
          exit();
    }

$date = date("Y-m-d");
$month = date('M');
$day1 = date('D');
$day = date('d');


$gid = $connect->prepare("SELECT MAX(bid) as maxGroup FROM dates");
$gid->execute();
$maxbid = $gid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($maxbid['maxGroup']){$bid=($maxbid['maxGroup']+1);}else{$bid=1;}

$day="Day".$bid;  

   if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
       $sal = $_POST['sal'];
       $count=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM dates WHERE month='$month' AND date='$date' and username='mrpopo'")->fetchColumn();

       if ($count >0){
$connect->query("UPDATE `dates` SET text='$sal' WHERE month='$month' AND date='$date' and username='mrpopo'");
      }
      else{
        $sql= ;
$connect->query("INSERT INTO `dates` (text, username,month,date,day) VALUES ('$sal', 'mrpopo', '$month', '$date', '$day')");

      }  
   }
?>
<form method="post">
<label><?php echo $day.' '. $month .' '.$day; ?></label><input type="text" name="sal" >
<button name="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir Mehrdad Dashti. it gives me an error .mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\compute\com.php on line 15